# Logging Method signature using swift

Tags: ios, cmd, swift, ios8

I am trying to rewrite my logging class and I would like to know how to substitute **PRETTY_FUNCTION** or NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) in a swift file in order to track the method calls?

Comment: Here is a logging library you could check out https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs

Comment: For anyone looking to implement logging functionality into their App or Framework: `Evergreen` is modeled after Python’s excellent `logging` module with adjustable log levels and everything you would expect from a logging framework:
https://github.com/viwid/Evergreen
It's based on a logger hierarchy that also allows you to adjust the verbosity of parts of your software, e.g. lower the log level for the part you are currently debugging. This also gives users of your framework the opportunity to configure the verbosity of your logging.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Check out a new library I've just published: https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger

It's a debug logging library for Swift.

The key to being able to use the `#function` macros, is to set them as default values to your logging function. The compiler will then fill them in using the expected values.

```
func log(logMessage: String, functionName: String = #function) {
    print("\(functionName): \(logMessage)")
}
```

Then just call:

```
log("my message")
```

And it works as expected giving you something like:

```
whateverFunction(): my message
```

More info on how this works: https://www.cerebralgardens.com/blog/entry/2014/06/09/the-first-essential-swift-3rd-party-library-to-include-in-your-project

Comment: The `__FUNCTION__` bug is definitely aggravating, confirmed that I see it in Beta 1.  I'll provide an update if I see it fixed in subsequent betas.

Comment: I have a workaround in https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger that deals with the ```__FUNCTION__``` bug. Since the bug always appends the function info to the end each time it's called, if you always call it twice, and use only the portion that's appended, you're good to go.

Comment: @DaveWood, bug still happens in Beta3, your workaround still needed.

Comment: @DaveWood, Beta6, bug still there.

Comment: @DmitryKonovalov Not sure what you did to generate that error. Make sure you have the latest bits (there was an important commit this morning even), and use Xcode 6.1. The sample projects should build without errors.

Answer (score 97):

Special literals in swift are as follows (from [the swift guide]

`#file` **String** The name of the file in which it appears.

`#line` **Int** The line number on which it appears.

`#column` **Int** The column number in which it begins.

`#function` **String** The name of the declaration in which it appears.

---

**Prior to Swift 2.2b4**, these were

(https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html)):

`__FILE__` **String** The name of the file in which it appears.

`__LINE__` **Int** The line number on which it appears.

`__COLUMN__` **Int** The column number in which it begins.

`__FUNCTION__` **String** The name of the declaration in which it appears.

You can use these in logging statements like so:

`println("error occurred on line \(__LINE__) in function \(__FUNCTION__)")`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I jumped the gun by starting after finishing the guide section only. What bothers me is that __FUNCTION__ doesn't include the class and I have to trim the file path and only keep the module name and the file name when using __FILE__ [ /Users/joe.xxxx/Documents/Experimental/Logger/Logger/ViewController.swift].

Answer (score 9):

I'd use something like this:

```
func Log(message: String = "", _ path: String = __FILE__, _ function: String = __FUNCTION__) {
    let file = path.componentsSeparatedByString("/").last!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").first! // Sorry
    NSLog("\(file).\(function): \(message)")
}
```

Improvements compared to previous answers:

- Uses NSLog, not print/println
- Does not use lastPathComponent which is not available on Strings anymore
- The log message is optional

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
class Log {
    class func msg(message: String,
        functionName:  String = __FUNCTION__, fileNameWithPath: String = __FILE__, lineNumber: Int = __LINE__ ) {
        // In the default arguments to this function:
        // 1) If I use a String type, the macros (e.g., __LINE__) don't expand at run time.
        //  "\(__FUNCTION__)\(__FILE__)\(__LINE__)"
        // 2) A tuple type, like,
        // typealias SMLogFuncDetails = (String, String, Int)
        //  SMLogFuncDetails = (__FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__) 
        //  doesn't work either.
        // 3) This String = __FUNCTION__ + __FILE__
        //  also doesn't work.

        var fileNameWithoutPath = fileNameWithPath.lastPathComponent

#if DEBUG
        let output = "\(NSDate()): \(message) [\(functionName) in \(fileNameWithoutPath), line \(lineNumber)]"
        println(output)
#endif
    }
}
```

Log using:

```
let x = 100
Log.msg("My output message \(x)")
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I used in: https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs
Its like XCGLogger but better.

```
func myLog<T>(object: T, _ file: String = __FILE__, _ function: String = __FUNCTION__, _ line: Int = __LINE__) {
    let info = "\(file).\(function)[\(line)]:\(object)"
    print(info)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will print only in debug mode:

```
func debugLog(text: String,  fileName: String = __FILE__, function: String =  __FUNCTION__, line: Int = __LINE__) {
    debugPrint("[\((fileName as NSString).lastPathComponent), in \(function)() at line: \(line)]: \(text)")
}
```

Result:

```
"[Book.swift, in addPage() at line: 33]: Page added with success"
```

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 3 and above:

```
print("\(#function)")
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4, based on all these awesome answers. ❤️

```
/*
 That's how I protect my virginity.
*/

import Foundation

/// Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048430/logging-method-signature-using-swift).
class Logger {

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    private init() {} // Disallows direct instantiation e.g.: "Logger()"

    // MARK: - Logging

    class func log(_ message: Any = "",
                   withEmoji: Bool = true,
                   filename: String = #file,
                   function: String =  #function,
                   line: Int = #line) {

        if withEmoji {
            let body = emojiBody(filename: filename, function: function, line: line)
            emojiLog(messageHeader: emojiHeader(), messageBody: body)

        } else {
            let body = regularBody(filename: filename, function: function, line: line)
            regularLog(messageHeader: regularHeader(), messageBody: body)
        }

        let messageString = String(describing: message)
        guard !messageString.isEmpty else { return }
        print(" └  \(messageString)\n")
    }
}

// MARK: - Private

// MARK: Emoji

private extension Logger {

    class func emojiHeader() -> String {
        return "⏱ \(formattedDate())"
    }

    class func emojiBody(filename: String, function: String, line: Int) -> String {
        return " \(filenameWithoutPath(filename: filename)), in  \(function) at #️⃣ \(line)"
    }

    class func emojiLog(messageHeader: String, messageBody: String) {
        print("\(messageHeader) │ \(messageBody)")
    }
}

// MARK: Regular

private extension Logger {

    class func regularHeader() -> String {
        return " \(formattedDate()) "
    }

    class func regularBody(filename: String, function: String, line: Int) -> String {
        return " \(filenameWithoutPath(filename: filename)), in \(function) at \(line) "
    }

    class func regularLog(messageHeader: String, messageBody: String) {
        let headerHorizontalLine = horizontalLine(for: messageHeader)
        let bodyHorizontalLine = horizontalLine(for: messageBody)

        print("┌\(headerHorizontalLine)┬\(bodyHorizontalLine)┐")
        print("│\(messageHeader)│\(messageBody)│")
        print("└\(headerHorizontalLine)┴\(bodyHorizontalLine)┘")
    }

    /// Returns a `String` composed by horizontal box-drawing characters (─) based on the given message length.
    ///
    /// For example:
    ///
    ///     " ViewController.swift, in viewDidLoad() at 26 " // Message
    ///     "──────────────────────────────────────────────" // Returned String
    ///
    /// Reference: [U+250x Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character)
    class func horizontalLine(for message: String) -> String {
        return Array(repeating: "─", count: message.count).joined()
    }
}

// MARK: Util

private extension Logger {

    /// "/Users/blablabla/Class.swift" becomes "Class.swift"
    class func filenameWithoutPath(filename: String) -> String {
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: filename).lastPathComponent
    }

    /// E.g. `15:25:04.749`
    class func formattedDate() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        return "\(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))"
    }
}
```

---

> Calling with `Logger.log()` -- (emoji is on by default):

[image: emojiLog]

---

> Calling with `Logger.log(withEmoji: false)`:

[image: regularLog]

---

> More usage examples:

```
Logger.log()
Logger.log(withEmoji: false)
Logger.log("I'm a virgin.")
Logger.log("I'm a virgin.", withEmoji: false)
Logger.log(NSScreen.min.frame.maxX) // Can handle "Any" (not only String).
```

Comment: Funny you use a `Logger` class, Apple introduced that in iOS 14 (I also [wrote about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974883/how-to-print-out-the-method-name-and-line-number-in-swift/66537565#66537565)). ;)

Comment: @PranavKasetti Indeed. I actually created a package around `Logger`. Take a look: https://github.com/backslash-f/applogger `Logger` is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

As of Swift 2.2, you can specify it using `Literal Expressions`, as described at the [Swift Programming Language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID383).

So if you had a `Logger` struct that had a function that logged where the error happened, then you would call it like this:

`Logger().log(message, fileName: #file, functionName: #function, atLine: #line)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take on it.

```
func Log<T>(_ object: Shit, _ file: String = #file, _ function: String = #function, _ line: Int = #line) {

var filename = (file as NSString).lastPathComponent
filename = filename.components(separatedBy: ".")[0]

let currentDate = Date()
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"

print("┌──────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────")
print("│ \(df.string(from: currentDate)) │ \(filename).\(function) (\(line))")
print("└──────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────")
print("  \(object)\n")}
```

Hope you enjoy.

[image]

Comment: I laughed at this!

Comment: This is h4x0r PR0 level logging

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the class and the function name in one go:

```
var name = NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder) + "." + __FUNCTION__
```

Comment: maybe `self.dynamicType` instead of `self.classForCoder` would be straightforward?

Answer (score 2):

this seems to work fine in swift 3.1

```
print("File: \((#file as NSString).lastPathComponent) Func: \(#function) Line: \(#line)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 support debugLog object with date, function name, file name, line number:

```
public func debugLog(object: Any, functionName: String = #function, fileName: String = #file, lineNumber: Int = #line) {
    let className = (fileName as NSString).lastPathComponent
    print("\(NSDate()): <\(className)> \(functionName) [#\(lineNumber)]| \(object)\n")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

****** **Possibly outdated**. *******

<sub>As pranav mentioned in the comments please use Logger for iOS 14+</sub>

---

There's a new library I have published: [**Printer**](https://github.com/hemangshah/printer).

It has many functions to let you log in different ways.

**To log a success message:**

```
Printer.log.success(details: "This is a Success message.")
```

**Output:**

```
Printer ➞ [✅ Success] [⌚04-27-2017 10:53:28] ➞ ✹✹This is a Success message.✹✹
[Trace] ➞ ViewController.swift ➞ viewDidLoad() #58
```

**Disclaimer**: This library has been created by me.

Comment: Just use `Logger` for iOS 14+.

Answer (score 0):

```
func Log<T>(_ object: T, fileName: String = #file, function: String =  #function, line: Int = #line) {
    NSLog("\((fileName as NSString).lastPathComponent), in \(function) at line: \(line): \(object)")
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of your answer

Comment: I took bit of everything from each answers below. For example instead of string it is object and you don't need to enter the label of argument so Log(object) and Log("test") would work

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version, using os_log, could be:

```
func Log(_ msg: String = "", _ file: NSString = #file, _ function: String = #function) {
    let baseName = file.lastPathComponent.replacingOccurrences(of: ".swift", with: "")
    os_log("%{public}@:%{public}@: %@", type: .default, baseName, function, msg)
}
```

Still heavy on string processing, if you can't afford that, just use os_log directly.