# Get swift function parameters dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, dynamictype

I am experimenting with a debug logging tool, and I want each run of a function to print out the Class Name, instance, function name, and its parameters. This is what I have so far

```
class Object {
    func exampleFunction(parameter1: String, parameter2: Int) {
        print("\(self.dynamicType)."+__FUNCTION__+"( <TODO: INSERT ALL PARAMETERS HERE AUTOMAGICALLY> )")

        //do function stuff
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can get the parameter list dynamically the similarly to how I get the function name and class type?

EDIT: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048430/logging-method-signature-using-swift) question on stack overflow that is trying to do a similar thing, but they don't know how to get the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The only official documentation on those literals is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html)

Which only describes about the following

`__FILE__`   The name of the file in which it appears.

`__LINE__`   The line number on which it appears.

`__COLUMN__`  The column number in which it begins.

`__FUNCTION__` The name of the declaration in which it appears.

So i guess you cannot get the method parameters.