# Swift function scope - referencing self (to mean "self as the enveloping function")

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Take this basic function:

```
func sampleFunction ()
{
    print( self )
}
```

Here `self` refers to the *class instance* that envelopes it, rather than - as might arguably make more sense - the *function* that envelopes it.

How does one get a reference to the enveloping *function* rather than its enveloping *class instance*?

Ideally, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
func sampleFunction ( value: Int )
{
    print( selfAsEnvelopingSampleFunction, value )
}
```

Comment: interesting question! I didn't even know I wanted to know this myself, but here's what I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048430/logging-method-signature-using-swift

Comment: I believe that it's already available by its name... for example `print( sampleFunction, value )` for `sampleFunction(2)` will output `(Function) 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print the name of the function, you can use [`__FUNCTION__`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID390)

```
print(__FUNCTION__)
```

in your print statement, otherwise just use `sampleFunction` as an argument .

Comment: Add a link to the documentation in your answer as a reference to make it complete. [Here's the link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID390)

Answer (score 1):

Instance methods are curried in swift. So you can get the function as referance.

```
struct User {
    func sampleFunc(name: String) {
        let f = User.sampleFunc(self)
        print(f, name)
    }
}
```

Here the f value is the function itself

Comment: thanks @mustafa, I did realise that already, and should've put that in the original question. I was actually looking for a generic, reusable phrase like 'self', that I wouldn't need to type out every time.