# Firebase observations duplicating data?

Tags: swift, firebase, core-data

If the conversation has already started, then I fetch messages from firebase  using the last message in the cache, as `self.fetchMessages(startingAt: lastMessageID!)`. This function is essentially the same as fetching all the messages, except it fetches starting at a point, as such:

```
   func fetchMessages(startingAt:String) {

    if started == true {
        print(startingAt)
        let messageRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(convoID!).queryOrderedByKey().queryStarting(atValue: startingAt)
    messageRef.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            print(value)
            let newMessage = message()
            newMessage.messageText =  value["content"] as? String
            newMessage.sender = value["sender"] as? String
            newMessage.messageID = snapshot.key
            newMessage.messageTime = value["time"] as? Int

            if snapshot.key == startingAt {
                print("firstItem")
            }
            else {
                self.messageList.append(newMessage)
                self.messagesTableView.reloadData()
                self.scrollToBottom()
                self.addMessageToCache(messageToCache: newMessage)
            }

            self.queryingStatus = true


        }

    }
}
}
```

It looks like multiple observations are being made from firebase, as if multiple observers are being added. For instance, when I add a message, the console log will show :

```
    {
    content = 0;
    sender = CAD54A563CAB99107D9BBDB7F2234FA3;
    time = 1532629519121;
}
adding
{
    content = 0;
    sender = CAD54A563CAB99107D9BBDB7F2234FA3;
    time = 1532629519121;
}
adding
{
    content = 0;
    sender = CAD54A563CAB99107D9BBDB7F2234FA3;
    time = 1532629519121;
}
adding
{
    content = 0;
    sender = CAD54A563CAB99107D9BBDB7F2234FA3;
    time = 1532629519121;
}
adding
{
    content = 0;
    sender = CAD54A563CAB99107D9BBDB7F2234FA3;
    time = 1532629519121;
}
adding
{
    content = 0;
    sender = CAD54A563CAB99107D9BBDB7F2234FA3;
    time = 1532629519121;
}
adding
{
    content = 0;
    sender = CAD54A563CAB99107D9BBDB7F2234FA3;
    time = 1532629519121;
}
```

It increases every time I open the screen. For instance, the first message won't be duplicated, the second message I send will be duplicated, if I reopen the screen and send a third message it will appear thrice in the snapshot... looks like multiple observers are being added?

Comment: That’s a long question with a lot of code, hardly a minimal example. One thought though, have you tried to place print statements at strategical places to see if some functions gets called when it shouldn’t or multiple times instead of just once. Don’t forget you can get func names etc easily when calling print, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974883/how-to-print-out-the-method-name-and-line-number-in-swift

Comment: @Jokaim I’ll try doing the print statements, also I’ll reduce the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, there were a few problems. First, the observers needed to be removed on the view did disappear. Second, conversations were being deleted from the cache because the function to delete conversations was called before the array of convos had fully loaded.