# Swift: how to convert argument to argument name string?

Tags: swift, logging

In order to do logging nicely, I want to know how to convert argument to argument name string In Swift.

I already know [Logging Method signature using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048430/logging-method-signature-using-swift).

I want to know how to log function argument as it is , following its value?

---

PS: I want to create a Util method helping logging.

```
func printMore(objName: Any){
    print("objName: \(objName)")
}
```

the `print("objName:...`, I want the 'objName' injected automatically.

Suck as conditions:

```
let foo = "Sark"
print("foo: \(foo)")
```

---

PPS: It is about Swift runtime. After I alloc some memory, I create some objects, how to get them through runtime instead of hard coding.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. Show some sample code and the log output you'd like to generate from that code.

Comment: @DuncanC, Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, if you called next method inside your function, it shows method declaration with all parameters:

```
func testFunction(param1: String, param2: String) {    
   print(#function)
}
```

> testFunction(param1:param2:)

Comment: It is too easy. I updated my question. And I did a little encouragement to you.

Answer (score 0):

Write C .

> U have to release it youself

---

object.description